# How did Begbie track Rents?

Tags: plot-explanation, trainspotting

In the movie *Trainspotting* when Mark "Rent Boy" Renton reads Diane's letter and Begbie arrives at his room, how did Begbie come to know where Rent was living?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"when Rent reads Diane's letter"...

So Diane had Rent's address, and Spud knew Diane was in touch with him when he speaks to her while mashed up on the kerb... everybody seems to know everybody in Leith and within the core group of 'best friends' these details are bound to get about, especially when you, perhaps, have a criminal psycho on the run demanding the London address from any one of these characters. Also, the film implies (and the book states specifically) that these guys spend a lot of time in London and that Sick Boy already has many 'contacts' down there (in the film this is primarily shown through his relationship with the hotel owner in the climax).